# Getting error {'error': {'code': -32600, 'message': 'Unsupported JSON-RPC protocol version'}, 'id': 1} when using eth_subscribe

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, polkadot

CODE: This is on the EVM chain moonbeam network

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json
url = 'ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:9944/'
ws = create_connection(url)
ws.send(json.dumps({"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads"]}))
print (ws.recv())
```

Error from above code:

`{'error': {'code': -32600, 'message': 'Unsupported JSON-RPC protocol version'}, 'id': 1}`

Documentation:

https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/get-started/eth-compare/rpc-support/

They have linked to the geth docs for the `eth_subscribe` method.

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/pubsub#create-subscription

According to this, expected output is:

```
>> {"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newHeads", {}]}
<< {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xcd0c3e8af590364c09d0fa6a1210faf5"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request should include `"jsonrpc":"2.0"`. E.g.

```json
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "eth_subscribe",
  "params": ["newHeads", {}]
}
```

See point 4 in https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out but you are fast. Thanks :)